# Using constants from the class within JUnit test class

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I'm kind of mediocre at Java at the moment, and new to JUnit, but I can't find the answer to this question elsewhere.

I want to use a constant variable defined within the class I am testing, within the Junit test case itself, but since it's a static final, it's not available.

The class I'm testing is as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final int HSIZE = 7;
    private static final int NUM_LOCS = 3;
    .
    .
    .

    void generateRandomLocations() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        String[] hPos = new String[NUM_LOCS]; 

        for (int i=0; i<NUM_LOCS; i++) {
            hPos[i] = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(HSIZE)); 
        } 
        setLocations(hPos);
    }
}
```

Simple enough, and it seems to work OK, but I'd like to add a test case in JUnit - something like the following:

```
@Test
void testGenerateRandomLocations() {
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();

    mc.generateRandomLocations();

    String[] check = mc.getLocations();
    assertEquals(sadc.NUM_LOCS, check.length);

    }
```

(The getter is defined, I just haven't included it here for brevity)

However (of course) sadc.NUM_LOCS is not available because it's only visible in MyClass.

How can I access this from a JUnit (5) test case?

Comment: you can change the visivility of your constants to public instead of private

Comment: Isn't this considered poor coding standards when they're only used within the class? Or is it considered OK to do this in order to define tests in this way?

Answer (score 1):

I've used `@VisibleForTesting` annotation which annotates why normally private variables and methods are protected instead. They're not fully visible, but can be accessed for testing purposes. I've used this with what were `private static final` variables.

The example I've seen/worked with used a file called `VisibleForTesting.java` that contained:

```
package your.pkg.here;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.SOURCE;
/**
 * Indicates that the class, method or field has greater
 * visibility than otherwise needed to enhance testability.
 */
@Retention(SOURCE)
public @interface VisibleForTesting {
}
```

Then within the class you want to test you set the method or variable to protected, and use the `@VisibleForTesting` annotation:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final int HSIZE = 7;

    @VisibleForTesting
    protected static final int NUM_LOCS = 3;

    void generateRandomLocations() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        String[] hPos = new String[NUM_LOCS]; 

        for (int i=0; i<NUM_LOCS; i++) {
            hPos[i] = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(HSIZE)); 
        } 
        setLocations(hPos);
    }
}
```

This allows the tests to see it, but the variable is not available to the public, and there is an explanation for why it's not private. `@VisibleForTesting` can also be found in Google's Guava library, so you could include that instead of adding `VisibleForTesting.java`, but I haven't used that.

Comment: Can we do same w/o changing access modifier?

Comment: No, you still need to have the access modifier set to protected. This just provides an explanation as to why it's not set to private.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using Powermockito. Whitebox has getInternalState.

see if it helps

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Bypass-Encapsulation

Answer (score -1):

**Simple answer**

Make variable `NUM_LOCS` public. However, this is a poor design.

**Better answer**

Instead of static variable, pass `NUM_LOCS` through constructor:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final int numLocs;

    public MyClass(int numLocs) {
        this.numLocs = numLocs;
    }

    //default ctor with default numLocs value
    public MyClass() {
        this.numLocs = 3;
    }

    //methods

}
```

Now, your test looks like this:

```
@Test
void testGenerateRandomLocations() {
    int expectedNumLocs = 7;
    MyClass mc = new MyClass(7);
    mc.generateRandomLocations();
    String[] check = mc.getLocations();
    assertEquals(expectedNumLocs, check.length);
}
```

and you can make a test to check default value is 3, too:

```
@Test
void testGenerateRandomLocations() {
    int expectedNumLocs = 3;
    MyClass mc = new MyClass(); //no args
    mc.generateRandomLocations();
    String[] check = mc.getLocations();
    assertEquals(expectedNumLocs, check.length);
}
```

Comment: If the attribute is fix and essential it is possibly not a poor design to increase the visibility of the class. If the size is meant to be fix it is even worse to define it inside of the constructor.

Comment: If attribute is needed to make tests and it's private, it's a poor design without any doubt. And if it's meant to be fix, it makes no sense to need it to write the test case. `assertEquals(3, check.length);` is enough.

Comment: The attribute is fixed, and the intent is simply to be able to scale it up later without changing every reference to "3".

Comment: If field is just used inside that class, it's not a good practice to make it public... Maybe, it's better to think about whether that test case it's useful and provides value.